# Grouping_by and percentage in calculating in dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need to have a table as result which contains data about persons and their percentage. Here you can see an example of how it could look like.

```
person   percentage
aa      17.04
bb      89.03
cc      67.99
dd      38.88
```

My dataset looks like this:

```
person points
aa     134
bb     234
cc     121
dd     134
```

My code is:

```
  df$points/187*100
```

But I get as a result only percentage, but not data of persons. What is a better way to solve it?

Comment: `df$percentage <- df$points/187*100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to calculate the percentage points of the point score of each person where 187 points equal 100% (in contrast to @Len Greski's answer):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(percentage = points/1.87)
```

with output:

```
  person points percentage
1     aa    134   71.65775
2     bb    234  125.13369
3     cc    121   64.70588
4     dd    134   71.65775
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to write the result of the calculation to the data frame, one would use the assignment operator `<-` to assign the result to a column in the data frame. There's no need to load the `dplyr` package for this because the Base R solution requires less code than the `dplyr` solution.

We can do this as noted in the comments, where we use the `$` form of the extract operator to assign the result to a named element in the `data.frame()` called `df`.

```
df$pct <- df$points/187*100
```

We can use the `$` form of the extract operator on the left side of the assignment operator because a data frame is also a `list()`.

Given the code in the question, some percentages will be greater than 100 because at least one row has a value greater than 187. Therefore, a more accurate percentage based on total points (column adds to 100) would be:

```
textFile <- "person points
aa     134
bb     234
cc     121
dd     134"

df <- read.table(text=textFile,header=TRUE)

df$pct <- df$points/sum(df$points)*100

df
sum(df$pct)
```

...and the output:

```
  person points      pct
1     aa    134 21.50883
2     bb    234 37.56019
3     cc    121 19.42215
4     dd    134 21.50883

> sum(df$pct)
[1] 100
```

If 187 is the total number of persons in the data frame, one might interpret the original 'percentage' as a rate (i.e. points per 100 persons).

```
 df$points_rate <- df$points/187*100
 df
```

...and the output:

```
> df$points_rate <- df$points/187*100
> df
  person points      pct points_rate
1     aa    134 21.50883    71.65775
2     bb    234 37.56019   125.13369
3     cc    121 19.42215    64.70588
4     dd    134 21.50883    71.65775
```

If one must use `dplyr` for the solution, the solution with the least code avoids the magrittr pipe operator `%>%` by simply naming the data frame in the `mutate()` function.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- mutate(df,pct = points / 187 * 100,
             points_rate = points / sum(points) * 100)

df
```

...and the output:

```
> df
  person points       pct points_rate
1     aa    134  71.65775    21.50883
2     bb    234 125.13369    37.56019
3     cc    121  64.70588    19.42215
4     dd    134  71.65775    21.50883
```

Finally, although the title of the question mentions grouping, neither the data nor code provided with the question require grouping functions to produce the output.

Comment: Your edit is a great explanation of the possible solutions to the question. For me one of the greatest things about dplyr is code readability. Therefore personally I like using the maggritr pipe for all transformations applied to a dataframe. This way it's easy to see right at the beginning of the code which data you are going to manipulate